# UseNavigate is giving error in my project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

When i am importing { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom" my app is working fine but when i am doing this `let navigate = useNavigate();` i am getting error and my project not running. I am getting this Error

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 The above error occurred in the <App> component:

    at App (http://localhost:3000/main.275edd721dcd59139133.hot-update.js:41:84)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:4026
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
scheduleRefresh @ react-dom.development.js:27795
renderer.scheduleRefresh @ react_devtools_backend.js:6514
(anonymous) @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:304
performReactRefresh @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:293
(anonymous) @ RefreshUtils.js:85
setTimeout (async)
enqueueUpdate @ RefreshUtils.js:83
executeRuntime @ RefreshUtils.js:243
$ReactRefreshModuleRuntime$ @ App.js:72
./src/App.js @ App.js:72
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
_requireSelf @ hot module replacement:102
apply @ jsonp chunk loading:444
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:344
internalApply @ hot module replacement:342
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:279
waitForBlockingPromises @ hot module replacement:233
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:277
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:276
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:256
Promise.then (async)
hotCheck @ hot module replacement:247
check @ dev-server.js:13
(anonymous) @ dev-server.js:55
emit @ events.js:153
reloadApp @ reloadApp.js:46
warnings @ index.js:227
(anonymous) @ socket.js:60
client.onmessage @ WebSocketClient.js:50
```

Please any one tell why this is happening with me.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include the most relevant part of your question. What is the *actual* error being reported? Please also include a [mcve] so we can cross reference the error and code stacktrace against the code producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not using the router that's why i am getting this error when i have used router in my project my project has been started.if you are also facing this issues please use router.